# How would you go about creating distorted textures like in Olga Bell's Music Video ATA?

Tags: texturing, camera, distort

I am guessing this is a basic question, but since I am fairly new to blender, I`d be happy for some help:

How would I go about texturing an abstract shape with a photograph so that from a certain vantage-point the texture reveals the original photograph?
The idea comes from [Olga Bell`s video ATA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=74&v=DEzuZlUB3zM)

Here are some images:
[image]
[image]

I have completed a [lesson on color displacement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFfTFYMld-8) which results in a blend that has the same vantage point effect, but follows different principles.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think they use this technique a lot:

- Create your 3D object. I've made a cube to make it simple.
- Choose the camera view and *Unwrap* your object with the *Project From View* option.
- Now as long as you keep the same view the picture will appear correct, but as soon as your camera will move it will deform. It's a little bit like the *Camera Mapping* technique except that you don't try to make your 3D object match with the picture.

[image]